# ios OTA via OneDrive not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ota

I have been successfully using Drop Box for IOS Over the Air Enterprise Distribution, however our company as part of a security lockdown, is stopping the use of DropBox.

I have been trying to use OneDrive with no luck with the Corporate or Personal Drive, I get the message "Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found." with the URL "itms-services"

I have used Share & copy link, below is the URL I am using to the manifest file, is there any changes required to be made to the link like DropBox?

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovuAwqVtXvggfsVeJcr8RtT3aXQ2Q
```

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

this URL should work (Assuming you are firing this link in WebView)

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovuAwqVtXvggfsVeJcr8RtT3aXQ2Q

Comment: Thank you for the response, the OneDrive link works find, until I add "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=" in front of the link, to install the .ipa, then I get "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Comment: if I reduce the font so the URL fits on one line & try and open from an email, I get the message "cannot connect to 1drv.ms" so it seems unhappy with the itms-services link

Comment: Still have this problem, has anyone found a solution using itms-services with SharePoint or OneDrive

Comment: @CoreyPowell, did you find a solution?